# Join and reduce arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I need to join and order 2 arrangements, and I have not succeeded.

the first array contains "categories" of pokemons

and the second array contains pokemons and some data.

I need to join both arrays, sum the power value of each pokemon and show them in this way

**expected result**

```
    [
        {fire: 19000},
        { rock: 2100 },
        {water: 1500}
    ]
```

**1st array "cateogries or types"**

```
const pokeTypes = [
  { uuid: 1, pokemonType: "fire" },
  { uuid: 2, pokemonType: "water" },
  { uuid: 3, pokemonType: "rock" }
];
```

**2nd array pokemons**

```
const pokemons = [
  {
    name: "geodude",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 900,
  },
  {
    name: "onix",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 1200,
  },
  {
    name: "squirtle",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "seadra",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 300,
  },
  {
    name: "goldeen",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 1100,
    },
  {
    name: "charmander",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 2000,
    },
   {
    name: "charmeleon",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 4000,
    },
   {
    name: "charizard",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 7000,
    },
   {
    name: "magmar",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 6000,
  },
];
```

I started doing a reducer and was able to generate an array of objects grouped by pokemonTypeId, I couldn't continue after this...

I tried

```
function sortPokemons() {
  result = pokemons.reduce(
    (h, pokemons) =>
      Object.assign(h, {
        [pokemons.pokemonTypeId]: (h[pokemons.pokemonTypeId] || []).concat({
          typeId: pokemons.pokemonTypeId,
        }),
      }),
    {}
  );
  console.log(result);
}
console.log(sortPokemons());
```

thanks!

Comment: Once you have your reduced array you need to map it to another array where pokemonTypeId -> pokemonType

Comment: @PaulRooney yes,

function sortPokemons() {
result = pokemons.reduce(
  (h, pokemons) =>
    Object.assign(h, {
      [pokemons.pokemonTypeId]: (h[pokemons.pokemonTypeId] || []).concat({
        typeId: pokemons.pokemonTypeId,
      }),
    }),
  {}
);
console.log(result);
}

console.log(sortPokemons());

Comment: @Valejo you should add it to the question. Its more readable when its formatted.

Comment: Also why have 3 objects in the result? Why not do it all in one e.g. `{ fire: 19000, water: 1500, rock: 2100 }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily and efficiently achive the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const pokeTypes = [
  { uuid: 1, pokemonType: "fire" },
  { uuid: 2, pokemonType: "water" },
  { uuid: 3, pokemonType: "rock" },
];

const pokemons = [
  {
    name: "geodude",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 900,
  },
  {
    name: "onix",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 1200,
  },
  {
    name: "squirtle",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "seadra",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 300,
  },
  {
    name: "goldeen",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 1100,
  },
  {
    name: "charmander",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: "charmeleon",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 4000,
  },
  {
    name: "charizard",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 7000,
  },
  {
    name: "magmar",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 6000,
  },
];
const map = new Map();
pokemons.forEach((o) =>
  map.has(o.pokemonTypeId)
    ? map.set(o.pokemonTypeId, map.get(o.pokemonTypeId) + o.power)
    : map.set(o.pokemonTypeId, o.power)
);

const result = pokeTypes.map((o) => ({ [o.pokemonType]: map.get(o.uuid) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using simple immutable programming: just use array methods `map()` and `reduce()`.

```js
const pokeTypes = [
  { uuid: 1, pokemonType: "fire" },
  { uuid: 2, pokemonType: "water" },
  { uuid: 3, pokemonType: "rock" },
];

const pokemons = [
  {
    name: "geodude",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 900,
  },
  {
    name: "onix",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 1200,
  },
  {
    name: "squirtle",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "seadra",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 300,
  },
  {
    name: "goldeen",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 1100,
  },
  {
    name: "charmander",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: "charmeleon",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 4000,
  },
  {
    name: "charizard",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 7000,
  },
  {
    name: "magmar",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 6000,
  },
];

const totals = pokeTypes.map(({uuid, pokemonType}) => {
  const total = pokemons.reduce((acc, {power, pokemonTypeId}) =>
    pokemonTypeId === uuid ? acc + power : acc
  , 0);
  return { [pokemonType] : total };
});

console.log(totals);
```

And if you want to a nice clean object `{ fire: 19000, rock: 2100, water: 1500 }`, which IMO is cleaner than array, replace the `.map()` with another `.reduce()`:

```
const totals = pokeTypes.reduce((acc, {uuid, pokemonType}) => {
  const total = pokemons.reduce((totalAcc, {power, pokemonTypeId})=>
    pokemonTypeId === uuid ? totalAcc + power : totalAcc
  , 0);
  return {
   ...acc,
   [pokemonType]: total,
  }
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pokeTypes = [
  { uuid: 1, pokemonType: "fire" },
  { uuid: 2, pokemonType: "water" },
  { uuid: 3, pokemonType: "rock" }
]; 

const pokemons = [
  {
    name: "geodude",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 900,
  },
  {
    name: "onix",
    pokemonTypeId: 3,
    power: 1200,
  },
  {
    name: "squirtle",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "seadra",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 300,
  },
  {
    name: "goldeen",
    pokemonTypeId: 2,
    power: 1100,
    },
  {
    name: "charmander",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 2000,
    },
   {
    name: "charmeleon",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 4000,
    },
   {
    name: "charizard",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 7000,
    },
   {
    name: "magmar",
    pokemonTypeId: 1,
    power: 6000,
  },
];

var data = pokeTypes.map(function(type) {
    var res = {};
    res[type.pokemonType] = pokemons.filter((item) => {
        return item.pokemonTypeId === type.uuid;
    }).reduce(function(sum, item) {
        return sum + item.power;
    }, 0);
    return res;
});
  
console.log(data);
```